# Excel Array Formulas %Difference Daily To Calculate St Deviation

Tags: arrays, excel

Using Bloomberg formula:

```
=BDH("AAPL US Equity", "PX_LAST", "01/01/2017", "30/06/2017", "Array=True", "dts=h")
```

Gives daily prices as an array in one cell:

```
[116.15,116.02, 116.61, 117.91, 118.99, 119.11, 119.75, 119.25, 119.04,...143.68,144.02]
```

My idea is to create two sets of the data offset by 1 day in the bloomberg formula, or preferably by simply deleting one piece of data from each end of each array.

```
[116.15 [116.02
116.02  116.61
116.61  117.91
117.91  118.99
118.99  119.11
119.11  119.75
119.75  119.25
119.25] 119.04]
```

I then use the formula:

```
=STDEV(SUMPRODUCT(1/([Array1]), [Array2]))
```

But I get an error `#DIV/1!`

Fairly sure I'm doing something wrong with the array division as sumproduct gives 1 number and I want the output of that to be an array to calculate the st.dev of.

I'm looking to create an array with each daily return:

```
[-0.001119242   0.00508533  0.011148272 0.009159528 0.001008488 0.005373184 -0.004175365    -0.001761006    0.008064516 -8.33333E-05    -0.001750146    0.001836701 0.000666667 -0.000916056    0.015920647 0.000492287 8.20075E-05 -0.002624026]
```

Then I can use the STDEV() formula to get a standard deviation.

I'd like to do this in one cell so as not to waste spreadsheet space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that B2 contains your Bloomberg formula returning the following string...

```
116.15, 116.02, 116.61, 117.91, 118.99, etc...
```

First define a name so that it returns those prices in the form of an array...

```
Name:  Prices

Refers to:  =EVALUATE("{"&Sheet1!$B$2&"}")
```

Then define another name so that it returns the number of elements in that array...

```
Name:  PriceCnt

Refers to:  =COUNT(Prices)
```

Now you can use the following array formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=STDEV((INDEX(Prices,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,2):INDEX($A:$A,PriceCnt)))))-INDEX(Prices,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,PriceCnt-1))))))/INDEX(Prices,N(IF(1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,PriceCnt-1))))))
```

Hope this helps!